# Tensorflow efficient Cyclegan history pool

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

in the [CycleGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10593.pdf) there is mention of history pool for discriminator. Thus we keep last e.g. 50 samples from generator and feed them to discriminator. Without history it's quite simple, we can utilize `tf.data.Dataset` and iterators to plug data into the network. But with the history pool, I did not get how to use the `tf.data.Dataset` api. 
The code inside the training loop looks something like

```
fx, fy = sess.run(model_ops['fakes'], feed_dict={
    self.cur_x: cur_x,
    self.cur_y: cur_y,
})

cur_x, cur_y = sess.run([self.X_feed.feed(), self.Y_feed.feed()])
feeder_dict = {
    self.cur_x: cur_x,
    self.cur_y: cur_y,
    self.prev_fake_x: x_pool.query(fx, step),
    self.prev_fake_y: y_pool.query(fy, step),
}
# self.cur_x, self.cur_y, self.prev_fake_x, self.prev_fake_y are just placeholders
# x_pool and y_pool are simple wrappers for random sampling from the history pool and saving new images to the pool
for _ in range(dis_train):
    sess.run(model_ops['train']['dis'], feed_dict=feeder_dict)
for _ in range(gen_train):
    sess.run(model_ops['train']['gen'], feed_dict=feeder_dict)
```

What bothers me about the code is it's ineffeciency, e.g. no possibility to preload next batch during training as with `tf.data` API's prefetch, but I don't see any way to use the `tf.data` API. 
Does it offer some kind of history pooling which could I use with prefetching and generally optimizing the data loading model?
Also, similar problem arises when I have some ratio between discriminators train op and generators train op.
If I want, for instance, run 2 steps of generators training operation per 1 step of discriminators, can it be done using same data? Because with `tf.data` API, new sample is drawn from iterator every time the sess.run is called.

Is there any way to implement that properly and efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out there is the history pooling already implemented in [TFGAN](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c985bd0dce0f8a7ccf334c9782d051c81ad00f1d/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/features/python/random_tensor_pool_impl.py#L50) tensorflow contrib repository.